# Get content from the window.location.href in LWR

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

In LWR, the window.location property is not supported because of LWR's version of Locker, but in the URL I have some data that I use in the code. Is there an approach to get content from the window.location.href in other way?

Comment: I dont think `window.location.href` is restricted. Can we see your code to check how are you using `window.location.href`?

Comment: @NagendraSingh You can check here (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/template_limitations.htm)  that window.location is restricted in the LWR

Comment: Can you share the snippet and LWC code ?

Comment: @NagendraSingh i can't, cause i am writing code based on this restriction. Do you have experience with LWR and can say that window.location.href works?

Comment: Swan, you are correct that window.location is not supported. What you can do is use document.URL to parse the information you need from the full URL. For example, you could replace window.location.host.indexOf('sitepreview') with document.URL.indexOf('sitepreview') in your JavaScript to evaluate what you're looking for. The CurrentPageReference approach that @Nagendra recommends will work if you're looking specifically for query parameters in a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I just tried and it did not work.
`window.location.href` does not work.

Here is a workaround though.
Try using `CurrentPageReference` from `lightning/navigation`

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
getpageRef(pageRef) {
    console.log(pageRef.state['c__key'])
}
```

So if you pass this in URL. `https://******-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/testlwrpage/?c__key=123`

Then it will fetch the param and give you 123.

So if you have multiple params just use it as below:

`https://*******-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/testlwrpage/?c__key=123&c__key2=1234`

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
getpageRef(pageRef) {

    for (const key of Object.keys(pageRef.state)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + pageRef.state[key])
    }
}
```